# Spring MVC: Appropriate extension point for wrapping API Responses

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a simple REST API, build using Spring MVC `@Controller`s and `@RequestMapping`. I'd like to start wrapping responses to provide additional with metadata.

For example, given a call that would return

```
HTTP GET: /users/1
{
    "userName" : "Jack Jackerson"
}
```

I'd like to wrap it, as follows:

```
{
    "metadata" : 
    {
        "callLimit" : "50",
        "callsRemaining" : "49"
    },
    "result" :
    {
        "userName" : "Jack Jackerson"
    }
}  ..etc..
```

Additionally, I'd like to support standard set of parameters for managing lists (`limit` and `offset`).

As this touches all the api methods, I'd like to implement it as a decorator of some spring internal service, so the methods themselves can focus on their actual logic, and keep this boilerplate stuff centralized.

I've started down the path of decorating the `HttpMessageConverter`'s that are registered, and wrapping them with a decorator.

However, this doesn't provide me access to the inbound request for methods that don't declare a `@RequestBody`.  (Many don't)

Ideally, I need to be higher in the stack  - `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters()` looks like a good candidate, but I don't know how to hook in here.

What options are available with Spring MVC to implement this type of API-Wide processing of request / responses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the implementation I used:

```
public class MetadataInjectingReturnValueHandler implements HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler {

    private final HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler delegate;

    public MetadataInjectingReturnValueHandler(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler delegate)
    {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean supportsReturnType(MethodParameter returnType) {
        return delegate.supportsReturnType(returnType);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleReturnValue(Object returnValue,
            MethodParameter returnType, ModelAndViewContainer mavContainer,
            NativeWebRequest webRequest) throws Exception {
        returnValue = wrapResult(returnValue); //Omitted
        delegate.handleReturnValue(returnValue, returnType, mavContainer, webRequest);
    }
}



@Component
public class MetadataInjectionFactoryBean implements InitializingBean {

    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite returnValueHandlers = adapter.getReturnValueHandlers();
        List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> handlers = Lists.newArrayList(returnValueHandlers.getHandlers());
        decorateHandlers(handlers);
        adapter.setReturnValueHandlers(handlers);
    }
    private void decorateHandlers(List<HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler> handlers) {
        for (HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler handler : handlers) {
            if (handler instanceof RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor)
            {
                MetadataInjectingReturnValueHandler decorator = new MetadataInjectingReturnValueHandler(handler);
                int index = handlers.indexOf(handler);
                handlers.set(index, decorator);
                log.info("Metadata Injecting decorator wired up");
                break;
            }
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: I think it's possible to use [`@ControllerAdvice`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice) combined with [`ResponseBodyAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyAdvice.html)to simplify this solution.

Comment: @AmirAbiri, it does not allow you to change the type of response. You can only enrich the response with some data, but not to wrap it object with other structure.