# Spring MVC / Rest - return standard response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, extjs

In Spring MVC, I am writing something using a controller, essentially performing REST plus a few additions.

Most of the functionality is called from ExtJS to spring, and to adhere to their conventions, the return is always a json object in the format:

```
{
    success: true,
    data: { ... }
}
```

or in the case of an error:

```
{
    success: false,
    message: { ... }
}
```

For the exceptions it is easy - Spring provides @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler etc so that errors can be trapped in one place and the standard response works.

However is there an easy way to force all of the valid responses to be passed through in the same way, so that the success element could be sent every time with the data sent back in the data object. in other words, currently for every call I have to do something like

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody

    public HashMap<String, Object> add(@RequestBody ManagedView targetTest) {
        ManagedView result = service.add(targetTest);
        HashMap<String, Object> ret = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ret.put("success", new Boolean(true));
        ret.put("data", result);
        return ret;
    }
```

whereas I would like to do is have something like

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)    
    public ManagedView  add(@RequestBody ManagedView targetTest) {
        return service.add(targetTest);

    }
// and each response intercepted by something like this

    public HashMap<String, Object> addWrapper(Object result) {

        HashMap<String, Object> ret = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        ret.put("success", new Boolean(true));
        ret.put("data", result);
        return ret;
    }
```

I appreciate I could just create a standard utility type function to do this but is there something that does this out of the box without me having to add the same code to all of the methods - preferably set globally.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am also looking for the same. You may add "total" in case of pagination

Comment: Do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13173341/spring-mvc-appropriate-extension-point-for-wrapping-api-responses

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerInterceptor`.

It contains `preHandle()`,`postHandle()` and `afterCompletion()` methods. In your case you can use `postHandle()` method to  manipulate the `ModelAndView` object before render it to view page,and it will be common point for all the controllers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution I just used, I went through several approaches until I found this one, which is the simplest one I think:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class StandardResponseBodyWrapAdvice implements ResponseBodyAdvice<Object> {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter returnType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
        return (AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(returnType.getContainingClass(), ResponseBody.class) != null ||
                returnType.getMethodAnnotation(ResponseBody.class) != null);
    }

    @Override
    public Object beforeBodyWrite(Object body, MethodParameter returnType, MediaType selectedContentType, Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> selectedConverterType, ServerHttpRequest request, ServerHttpResponse response) {
        ApiResponseDTO<Object> resp = new ApiResponseDTO<>();
        resp.setVersion("1.0");
        resp.setSuccess(true);
        resp.setData(body);
        return resp;
    }
}
```